# Reset Firefox sync password without losing everything

Tags: firefox, passwords, sync, mozilla

I have lost the password to my Firefox/Mozilla account. I'm currently logged in with it on several devices.

When I go to "reset password", Mozilla says:

> When you reset your password, you reset your account. You may lose some of your personal information (including history, bookmarks, and passwords). That’s because we encrypt your data with your password to protect your privacy.

Does this mean it will wipe the stuff currently in my local Firefox installation? Is there a way to back it up first and then restore after resetting the password?

(I do not have any of the other account recovery methods set up.)

Comment: You will indeed effectively will lose access to that data unless you export it before you reset the password to the account. I am not aware of any process to export your browsing history.  You should be able to import passwords and bookmarks into another browser, to allow you to reset the synchronization, and import them back into Firefox.

Comment: If indeed those data are encrypted with the password, there is no way to access them without the password.

Answer (score 3):

You can [export all logins](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/export-login-data-firefox) as plain text, but you *must enter the password* to start the export, so that's of no help to you.

- First, make copies of the entire profile on all machines before doing anything else.
- Much of the data is kept in that profile in *places.sqlite*, such as an extensive history of all URL's visited in table *moz_places*. Use any *Sqlite* tool, such as [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/), to view the tables. Export URL's with `select url, title from moz_places order by url;` and copy data to a spreadsheet. Or just keep the whole file, in case resetting password loses data.
- Bookmarks are easily [exported](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/export-firefox-bookmarks-to-backup-or-transfer).

  - In the main menu, click *Bookmarks | Manage Bookmarks*.
  - Click *Import & Backup | Export Bookmarks to HTML* and follow directions.
- As for other settings, if they're in the local profile, they should not be lost, but if stored *only* in the cloud, they'll be gone.
- If you have the [recovery key](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/reset-your-firefox-account-password-recovery-keys), you can reset the password safely.
- Finally, you can reset the password [without that key](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/ive-lost-my-firefox-sync-account-information), but, "Any data you have on the server **will be erased** when you reset your password," as you stated.

You might contact Mozilla support, but don't be too sanguine.

Comment: I'm not too concerned about logins - I use a different password manager. Mostly I want to keep history, bookmarks and preferences. Does that change anything?

Comment: Exporting bookmarks is easy, and history is kept in profile, in places.sqlite, unencrypted. Answer to be updated